# Why calling constructor with enum argument failed while using it as class field?

Tags: c++, enums, constructor, constants

I wrote a simple class constructor with one argument of enum type.

```
enum Kind {
    One,
    Two
};
class KindClass {
private:
    Kind fKind;

public:
    explicit KindClass(Kind kind) : fKind(kind) {}
};
```

Then make a global constant of it and it work.

```
static const KindClass globalKindClass(One);
```

But when making const field of it compile failed with error : "error: ‘One’ is not a type"

```
class UserClass {
private:
    static const KindClass kindClass(One);
};
```

What's the problem ? And how to solve it ?

https://godbolt.org/z/Yn45objnd

Comment: You cannot define members with direct initialization syntax (the one with parens) in C++, IIRC. Try `... kindClass = KindClass(One);` instead, maybe add `inline` before `static const`.

Comment: "static const KindClass kindClass = One; " And "inline static const KindClass kindClass = One; " failed with "conversion from 'Kind' to non-scalar type 'const KindClass' requested." error

Comment: @MohsenTi its because of the vexing parse in C++. That statement looks like a function declaration to the compiler.

Comment: Obligatory [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis.  An hour long presentation on the initialization syntax pain point in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use curly braces and `constexpr` to fix it:

```
class KindClass {
private:
    Kind fKind;

public:
    explicit constexpr KindClass(Kind kind) : fKind(kind) {}
};

class UserClass {
private:
    static constexpr KindClass kindClass{One};
};
```